# How to create a symbol with arrows and an arc in QGIS

Tags: qgis, symbology, style, markers, visualisation

I'm using QGIS 2.18 and wondering if there's a fairly simple way to create a symbol with an arrow on the end of a ray, and an arc in between.

[image: Arrows]

The thing that makes it complex is that the angle is not consistent.  Also, I always want the arc to travel from the first line drawn to the second line drawn so I can show angles greater than 180.  In my drawing point 1 is the left most arrow, point 2 the center, and point three the other arrow.  So the arc would travel from line 1-2 to 2-3.

Comment: You may get some ideas from these answers concerning similar topics: [first answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/230989/87487), [second answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/233514/87487). Otherwise, I can try to solve your specific issue if you add more information.

Comment: @mgri your second answer ended up being the closest to what I needed to do.  I ended up having to rebuild my shapefile, and reorient my approach, but the turned out to be a good thing.  If you'll put this in as an answer, I'll happily mark it as solved. :)

Comment: I'm glad you found it useful! I posted it as an answer, but feel free to edit your question with more information for receiving a targeted solution. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I recently answered to a couple of questions:

[Showing antenna symbols on the map: point symbols or features (polygons)](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/181706/showing-antenna-symbols-on-the-map-point-symbols-or-features-polygons)

[Creating sector lights in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/229961/creating-sector-lights-in-qgis)

related to similar topics. So, an approach would be recurring to *geometry generators* from the *Style* properties, assuming to edit the fields of your layer with information about angles, azimuths, lengths, and so on (it will depend on your skills with Field Calculator or PyQGIS).

The issue should be accomplished by creating three geometry generators (two for the arrows and one for the arc), following an approach which would be similar to the one I used in the links posted above.